# Adjacency matrix creation from edgelist

Tags: graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

```
data1 = { 'node1': [1,1,1,2],
     'node2': [2,3,6,4],
     'weight': [1,1,1,1], }
```

This is the edgelist of a graph.I want to create adjacency matrix from it.The networkx code is showing this output:

```
output:

[[0 1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0]]
but the actual output should be:

[[0 1 1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 1 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

In my opinion the second one should be the output a since in a adjacency matrix the rows and columns represent the nodes of the graph then if the adjacency matrix has only 5 rows and 5 columns then it would be like the graph has 5 nodes only when in fact it has 6 nodes.Its just that the 5 node is not there in the graph.What is the correct output according to mathematical definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a maths question.  You have a correct understanding of what an adjacency matrix should be.

Your problem is a software problem. The networkx code is correct; only 5 vertices were specified in the graph definition: vertices $1,2,3,4,6$. There simply is no vertex called $5$.

To get the behaviour you want, you need to tell networkx that the graph has another vertex, $5$.

Please don't follow up here with questions about how you should get networkx to do this; it's off-topic for a maths forum.  Raise a question in stackoverflow or similar.

Comment: I wanted to just check my understanding of the adjacency matrix as I am a newbie...So the second output is correct right according to graph theory?

Comment: Both adjacency matrices are correct according to graph theory, but they answer different questions. The second output matrix is correct if the graph you specified (using a list of edges) has 6 vertices and the rows/columns correspond to vertices 1,2,3,4,5,6 in that order.  The first output matrix is correct if your graph only has 5 vertices (labelled 1,2,3,4,6). You expect the software to add what you see as a missing vertex '5' because there's a vertex labelled '6'; the software is doing what it does because it only sees 5 vertices (1,2,3,4,6) occurring in the edges you specified.